# Difficult Trigonometry Concurrency

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

### Problem Statement

In arbitrary $\Delta ABC$, $I$ is the incenter.

$D,E,F$ are feet of perpendicular from $I$ on $\overline{BC}, \overline{CA}, \overline{AB}$.

$D',E',F'$ are on $\overrightarrow{ID}, \overrightarrow{IE}, \overrightarrow{IF}$ such that $ID'=IE'=IF'$.

Prove that $\overrightarrow{AD'}, \overrightarrow{BE'}, \overrightarrow{CF'}$ are concurrent.

---

### My Work - What I Have Done So Far

I drew a circle with centre at $I$ and radius as $IE'$. I immediately noticed that $\overrightarrow{IA}$ is perpendicular bisector of $\overline{E'F'}$, $\overrightarrow{IB}$ is perpendicular bisector of $\overline{F'D'}$, $\overrightarrow{IC}$ is perpendicular bisector of $\overline{D'E'}$. Also that since $\Delta DEF \sim\Delta D'E'F'$, $D =90 - \frac A2, E = 90 - \frac B2, F = 90 - \frac C2$. My attempts to use the trigonometric version of Ceva's Theorem were also in vain.

---

Also, I have no background in vectors and complex numbers. Any proof given in only pure geometry or trigonometry would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Hints are also equally appreciated. Any help from you would be really nice.

Comment: Hint: This is a particular case of Jacobi's theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_theorem_(geometry) ).

Comment: Let the intersection of lines BE' and CF' be H.  We have:

$\angle E'HC=\angle F'HB$

$\angle E'HA=\angle F'HA$

Summing these relation we get:

$\angle AHB=\angle AHC$

 IA is  the bisector of $\angle BAC$ and also  the bisector of $\angle E'HF'$   that is  IA must cross point H.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks a ton. Problem solved. I used triangle congruency to arrive to the solution.

Comment: @sirous thanks a lot. This is another solution.